# Is it possible to prevent Google Docs From converting PDF?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api, google-docs, google-apps

I'd like to open a PDF in Google Docs (not the previewer) without having Docs convert the file, 3rd Party PDF Viewers are not an option as I need to run a Google Script on the file also.  PDF->Doc conversion is completely useless, as it removes all formatting and leaves a worthless document in it's wake.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is not.  Google Apps script DocumentApp can only work with Google Docs type files anyway.
Depending on what you are trying to accomplish you could look at the DriveApp Apis, but any modifications to the Document contents require it to be a google type file.